# Cannot create more than 15 topics in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

Me and my colleague were testing out Kafka on a 3 nodes cluster and we encountered this problem were trying to test the performance of sending message to multiple topics. We can't create more than 15 topics. The first 15 topics works fine. But when trying to create the 16th topic(and topics onward), a lot of errors started to appear in the 2 follower servers.

One with a lot of errors like this:
`ERROR [ReplicaFetcherThread-0-1], Error for partition [__consumer_offsets,36] to broker 1:org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnknownServerException: The server experienced an unexpected error when processing the request (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)`

The other with errors like this:
`[2017-06-16 18:44:07,146] ERROR [KafkaApi-1] Error when handling request {replica_id=2,max_wait_time=500,min_bytes=1,max_bytes=10485760,topics=[{topic=__consumer_offsets,partitions=[{partition=6,fetch_offset=5,max_bytes=1048576},{partition=36,fetch_offset=3,max_bytes=1048576},{partition=18,fetch_offset=0,max_bytes=1048576}]},{topic=multi-test-12,partitions=[{partition=1,fetch_offset=1,max_bytes=1048576}]},{topic=multi-test-11,partitions=[{partition=2,fetch_offset=1,max_bytes=1048576}]},{topic=__consumer_offsets,partitions=[{partition=0,fetch_offset=5,max_bytes=1048576},{partition=45,fetch_offset=0,max_bytes=1048576}]},{topic=multi-test-16,partitions=[{partition=0,fetch_offset=0,max_bytes=1048576}]},{topic=__consumer_offsets,partitions=[{partition=27,fetch_offset=0,max_bytes=1048576},{partition=12,fetch_offset=0,max_bytes=1048576},{partition=9,fetch_offset=0,max_bytes=1048576}]},{topic=multi-test-10,partitions=[{partition=0,fetch_offset=0,max_bytes=1048576}]},{topic=multi-test-9,partitions=[{partition=2,fetch_offset=0,max_bytes=1048576}]},{topic=__consumer_offsets,partitions=[{partition=39,fetch_offset=0,max_bytes=1048576}]},{topic=multi-test-4,partitions=[{partition=1,fetch_offset=1,max_bytes=1048576}]},{topic=__consumer_offsets,partitions=[{partition=21,fetch_offset=10,max_bytes=1048576}]},{topic=multi-test-3,partitions=[{partition=2,fetch_offset=0,max_bytes=1048576}]},{topic=multi-test-13,partitions=[{partition=0,fetch_offset=1,max_bytes=1048576}]},{topic=__consumer_offsets,partitions=[{partition=3,fetch_offset=10,max_bytes=1048576},{partition=48,fetch_offset=0,max_bytes=1048576}]},{topic=multi-test-8,partitions=[{partition=0,fetch_offset=0,max_bytes=1048576}]},{topic=__consumer_offsets,partitions=[{partition=33,fetch_offset=0,max_bytes=1048576},{partition=30,fetch_offset=15,max_bytes=1048576},{partition=15,fetch_offset=0,max_bytes=1048576}]},{topic=multi-test-1,partitions=[{partition=1,fetch_offset=1,max_bytes=1048576}]},{topic=multi-test-0,partitions=[{partition=2,fetch_offset=0,max_bytes=1048576}]},{topic=multi-test-2,partitions=[{partition=1,fetch_offset=1,max_bytes=1048576}]},{topic=__consumer_offsets,partitions=[{partition=42,fetch_offset=3,max_bytes=1048576},{partition=24,fetch_offset=0,max_bytes=1048576}]}]} (kafka.server.KafkaApis)
kafka.common.NotAssignedReplicaException: Leader 1 failed to record follower 2's position -1 since the replica is not recognized to be one of the assigned replicas  for partition multi-test-16-0.
    at kafka.cluster.Partition.updateReplicaLogReadResult(Partition.scala:246)
    at kafka.server.ReplicaManager$$anonfun$updateFollowerLogReadResults$2.apply(ReplicaManager.scala:920)
    at kafka.server.ReplicaManager$$anonfun$updateFollowerLogReadResults$2.apply(ReplicaManager.scala:917)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at kafka.server.ReplicaManager.updateFollowerLogReadResults(ReplicaManager.scala:917)
    at kafka.server.ReplicaManager.fetchMessages(ReplicaManager.scala:462)
    at kafka.server.KafkaApis.handleFetchRequest(KafkaApis.scala:530)
    at kafka.server.KafkaApis.handle(KafkaApis.scala:81)
    at kafka.server.KafkaRequestHandler.run(KafkaRequestHandler.scala:62)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)`

We assigned a replication factor of 2 and a partition of 3 for each topic and every topic is created in the same way.I deleted and recreated each topic manually just to make sure that 15-16 is the exact number that everything went wrong.

Comment: have you any error log in controller.log on your leader broker ?

Comment: Anything about hitting the open file limit in the logs?

Comment: @QuentinGeff No, there's nothing in controller.log....

Comment: @dawsaw No, It just says "UnknowServerException". Also, I changed the open file limit to a relatively high value(2000) earlier.

Comment: Honestly that is still probably much too small. Go to something like 60000. Each log segment has 3 file descriptors required.

Comment: @dawsaw sorry, checked the number, we set it at 10000.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, weird problems seems to always have weird answers.
Turns out, the problem is that one of our node is using a x32 cpu, switching it to a x64 machine solved the problem.